# NumberFormatter::formatCurrency is not showing a currency symbol

Tags: php, currency, intl, numberformatter

I'm using *NumberFormatter::formatCurrency* to display formatted currency values, like this;

```
$value = 395;
$fmt = numfmt_create('en_GB', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo numfmt_format_currency($fmt, $value, 'gbp');
```

On my Windows dev box, and Centos UAT box, this outputs the desired **£395**.

But on the production Centos box, it outputs **gbp395**.

Any idea what is missing? I have checked intl extension is enabled.

Is there something wrong with my locale files perhaps? When I type

**locale -a**

in command line, I get a long list of locales, of which en_GB is one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `en_GB` is not a valid locale on your system. Try `en_GB.UTF-8` or `en_GB.ISO-8559-1` f.e.

Answer (score 0):

The `NumberFormatter` class is incorrect and the GBP needs to be in capital like so:`'GBP'`

Try this:

```
$value = 395;
$currencyFormat = new NumberFormatter('en_GB', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);

echo $currencyFormat->formatCurrency($value, 'GBP');
```

This will render `£395.00`